# How achieve manual parsing with Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

My app have to get some data from an API, store it into his database and display it (Cursor, CursorLoader, etc.).

For now, I use a simple HTTPClient and [GSON Reader](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) to convert directly my JSON response to [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html).
This avoids app crash when an old device parse large JSON file.

I am trying Retrofit for my API call. I don't want to create some middle business POJO. I would like to create some [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) and put it in [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html). I want Retrofit to do this.

Someone know how to achieve this ? Or maybe I missing out something ?